# How to check if apt proxy configuration is correct?

Tags: apt, proxy, ping

I have to use a proxy server which requires authentication. So, I need to update the **apt.conf** file to include my proxy settings. All fine. What I need is to check that the configuration is correct so that when I try *apt-get update*, I'll connect to the relevant repositories, etc.

Is there a way to check this without downloading anything to the PC (without *update*, *install*, *upgrade*, etc.)? In short: I'm looking for a way to just **ping** the repositories without any actual download happening.

Any other ways to validate the apt proxy settings is also welcome...

**Edit:** I read the manual but I couldn't see the functionality to be available by a simple option/flag. Maybe there is a hack?

**Update:** So, far the only solution I have is to **apt-get install** a tiny package and then remove it afterwards. But, I don't really like this approach. What if the package is already installed on the machine? Will apt-get still connect to the repositories (to check if the package is up-to-date)?

**Update2:** Apparently there is no solution to all the requirements I put in the question. I'll pick the answer with the closest to what I want.

Comment: What about a try? Make changes; try apt; if it fails - revert the changes ;)

Comment: @Serge Try what exactly? That's what I'm after. I don't want to use apt-get install or apt-get update, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apt-get update` is the way I'd do it. It hits all repositories.

Failing that, you could pretend to force the reinstallation of a small package with `apt-get clean; apt-get -d --reinstall install hostname` (this will mark the package as to-be-installed, so pick a package that's already installed).

Comment: Thank you. I think this is the closest we can get to what I wanted to do...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I realize this is an 11-year old question, but seeing as it's in the Top 5 search results that brought me here, I decided to solve the problem with the following script that I wrote:

[APT Proxy Checker @ My Github Repository](https://github.com/hastmu/apt-proxy-detect)

This script checks whether your proxy works with the desired repository URL. If the check fails, the script sets the proxy to nothing which will directly connect. This allows APT to work with a sane proxy or a buggy one, as I've included an APT hook in the script, as most other solutions seem to have overlooked this.